# SFTP - remove files

Tags: console, sftp

I have a batchfile with SFTP instruction to download txt files (cron job), basically: `get *.txt`

Wondering what the best method is to delete those files after the server has downloaded them. The only problem being that the directory is constantly being updated with new files, so running `rm *.txt` afterwards **won't work**.

I've thought of a couple complex ways of doing this, but no command line based methods. So, I thought I'd shoot a query out to you guys, see if there's something I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Could you please clarify? If the directory is constantly updated with new files, doesn't it mean you need to **constantly** remove them? Why isn't `rm *.txt` as the ending part of your cron job not good?

Comment: Because then he would delete files he hasn't yet moved.

Comment: Thanks @Corbin, somehow I wasn't sure the OP meant removing via SFTP. I agree with Vikas, then.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to delete a file abc.txt from the folder named document.

I visited the folder using cd and then typed the command "rm abc.txt" and hit enter.

I got the message "Removing /home/document/abc.txt" and after doing ls my abc.txt file was not there. Hope this answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a list of all the files that were downloaded and then issue ftp delete/mdelete commands with the exact file names.

Comment: I thought about this (except sftp of course), I would create the list of downloaded files (ls >> list.txt), and upload it back to the server. But I can't find out how to remove files, where it takes a file input which contains the filenames.